# How to apply physics when you have sub frame state changes?

Tags: physics, state

I'm currently calculating my physics every 1/100th of a second and using a state machine to manage the current state of the player.
In my main loop I'm checking user input and transitioning the state as needed and then my physics code checks the state to apply the appropriate forces.

Pseudo:

```
if (fsm.state == walking) {
    velocity += walkVelocity;
}
```

However, the issue I think I've noticed with this is; what if a full state transition occurs between two physics frames. For example the user taps jump so quickly they transition from jumping to falling happens so quickly that the physics code hasn't got a chance to see that a jump was requested and therefore doesn't apply the change in velocity.

This is a simple example, but I'm feeling that states maybe shouldn't be used this way. Maybe the key presses themselves need to be fed directly into the physics code (so that it can have access to durations and order of events) and then **it** (the physics code) updates the states accordingly.

Is this the common way of arranging flow? Or am I missing something? I.e. should it be:

> Input -> state change -> physics

Or should it be more like:

> Input -> physics -> state change

I've seen state machines used with event systems before. So state changes are raised as events which subscribers can respond to. However the physics code still needs to run at fixed timesteps so it needs to be able to query for 'things which have occurred'.

Comment: Either ignore the input when it happens between frames or ensure the input is valid for at least one frame.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how to ensure it though?

Comment: Why bother with complex synchronizing/event systems?(do you need events somewhere else in your project too?) Have input set a bool flag, each physics iteration check those flags, process them and reset them(only if needed). This way, key press will "wait" for next physics iteration.

Comment: @wondra The duration of a keypress drives the physics calculations therefore a simple boolean won't suffice. I know 1/100th of a second is pretty high resolution but there is nothing to say this might not need to change.

Comment: You can renew the flag if the key is still pressed or query the key state each physics iteration. But if the keypress was shorter then 1/100s you cannot do anything about it, I guess. If you need extremly precise physics simulations I am afraid you wont be able to do it on your HW. Not even common SW is designed to do that (there is RT linux distribution I heard, if that will help you).

Comment: You could just remember all the user actions until the next physics calculation round.

Comment: Trilarion I considered this, like a list sorted by time. @wondra I'm starting to agree with you. If the user presses two keys independently between frames - does it __really__ matter if they are treated as simultaneous. I'm thinking of not worrying. Now the question remains do I keep the state system driving the physics or drive it using raw keypresses? My concern being; physics dictates (to a point) what state is viable.